# Error at importing module

Tags: python, python-import

I have been writing some code and used it as a module. This was working properly, until this morning one of the modules would not load.

I have multiple programs in one direction. most of them load, except for two.
I have tried importing it using:

```
import company.a
from company import a
```

Both does not work.
However the following things both do work:

```
import company.b
from company import b
```

Both are in the same folder, containing **__init__.py**.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: So, it used to work under the same conditions (including the dir where you launch _python_ from)? Also is there any module (let's call it _c_) in the same folder that still works?

Comment: The error is:  ImportError: No module named formulas. I worked fine before. There are multiple modules called c in the folder still working. I have not made any changes to the python dir, or anything like it.  The problem has been solved by renaming the folder however, so it's not a big issue anymore, just weird

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it did work when I made an exact copy of the company folder, and named it company2.

the following does work:

```
from company2 import a
```

while it is the exact same file, in an folder containing exactly the same, with a different name.

Solved for now, although I am curious why changing the name of the folder made the difference

Comment: Maybe the company's name was similar to some standard/installed library and it was trying to import a library from that library instead from the folder.

Then when you renamed it to company2 there wasnt any installed library with that name and actually imported the library a

Comment: If you are curious you could install ipython and open a shell terminal typing ipython and thenwrite: import company and company?? with the question marks and it will show you the file/folder .py it's loading